# MySQL modify all field lengths

Tags: mysql

Is there any way you can update the length of all fields in MySQL? I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY * VARCHAR(150);
```

But no joy. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is one of the very few times a cursor makes good sense--you'll have to loop through `information_schema` and run `alter` statements. That being said, the real question I have for this is: Why?! Surely you have integers and other columns, right?

Comment: Having to do this is indication of bad database design or some misunderstanding. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: yep. I  just imported a bunch of fields from a csv file. All save for one of the 30+ fields are varchar. I just want to adjust the length as they all defaulted to 100. Is there someway to specify the length on importation?

Comment: @DarwinTech How did you import them?

Comment: actually, just using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use info from `information_schema` database to generate query for you.

If you need to change all varchar(100) columns to varchar(150) in your table `myTable` use query:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE `myTable`', 
                GROUP_CONCAT( 
                  CONCAT( '\nMODIFY ', COLUMN_NAME, ' VARCHAR(150) ' ),
                '' ) 
             ) AS query
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 100
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

and then copy/paste output as another query to do the actual job.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must be a way. When I plugged this into the mysql command line it gave me the query, which I could then copy/paste to actually alter the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify each column specifically.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
MODIFY col_1 VARCHAR(150),
MODIFY col_2 VARCHAR(150),
MODIFY col_3 VARCHAR(150);
```

Note that all modifications can be done in a single "pass", so this is more efficient than running n individual `ALTER TABLE` calls.

Comment: I realize I can do it on a per-column basis, I was just hoping for a more concise (i.e. lazy) way.